# Linux ext4 incremental backup tool produces individual files not one

Tags: ubuntu, backup, rsync, ext4, btrfs

I want to backup ext4 files with size (<100MB) as they are, NOT in one single archive file (like with dump or tar).

Can you recommend me a tool that keeps the directories/files structure in the destination ?
I am aware of rsync with --link-dest. This seems to work. Is there another method that can store more versions say for 7 days and allow restore of any of them ?

I am considering btrfs file system with all its tools. I will be uploading/downloading files via an API, with hundreds of users. Is btrfs worth it (no file size limit) or just too slow compared to ext4 for my purpose ?

Comment: As an answer for your first question I'd recommend to have a look at [rsnapshot](https://rsnapshot.org).

Comment: Or `rdiff-backup`